# mysql enterprise backup on windows restore

Tags: mysql

I am restoring a MYSQL database using a MYSQL enterprise backup. The directory is created successfully, but commands to restore do not work. Here are the commands I have tried:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Enterprise Backup 3.7>mysqlbackup --defaults-file="D:\DB_backup1\mysql_backup\2012-06-13_15-38-56\backup-my.cnf" 
--datadir=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\mysql --backup-dir=D:\DB_backup1\mysql_backup\2012-06-13_15-38-56 copy-back

MySQL Enterprise Backup version 3.7.1 [Tue 03/20/2012 ]
Copyright (c) 2003, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

INFO: Starting with following command line ...
 mysqlbackup
        --defaults-file=D:\DB_backup1\mysql_backup\2012-06-13_15-38-56\backup-my.cnf
        --datadir=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\mysql
        --backup-dir=D:\DB_backup1\mysql_backup\2012-06-13_15-38-56 copy-back

Error: Found extraneous commands at the end.
Use --help option for usage description.

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Enterprise Backup 3.7>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to restore the database. Following is the mysql enterprise backup command that worked for me, it required a change in the my.ini file in mysql installation directory.

mysqlbackup
--defaults-file=H:\db_backup_from_qa\mysql_backup\2012-06-13_15-38-56\backup-my.cnf
--backup-dir=H:\db_backup_from_qa\mysql_backup\2012-06-13_15-38-56
--datadir=H:\mysql\data copy-back

values of the parameters:
--defaults-file=H:\db_backup_from_qa\mysql_backup\2012-06-13_15-38-56\backup-my.cnf, this is path to .cnf file created while preparing the backup for restore.
--backup-dir=H:\db_backup_from_qa\mysql_backup\2012-06-13_15-38-56, this is the path where directory named data exists, its || to backup-my.cnf
--datadir=H:\mysql\data copy-back, this is path to data directory inside mysql installation.

Now the most important was to comment `datadir=H:\mysql\data` entry in my.ini inside mysql installation, as soon as I changed this I was able to restore the db.

But still a issue exist, I am not able to start mysql now, getting error 1067.

Finally found the solution to error 1067.

Rename the 2 log file, do not delete, and restart the mysql service.